# SQL Logic Operator Precedence Or and ()

Tags: sql, oracle10g, operators, operator-precedence

I am changing this

```
(NVL(N.col1,'-') <> NVL(O.col1,'-')) OR
(NVL(N.col2,-1) <> NVL(O.col2,-1))
```

to

```
NVL(N.col1,'-') <> NVL(O.col1,'-') OR
NVL(N.col2,-1) <> NVL(O.col2,-1) OR
```

in a trigger's when clause as it is exceeding the size allowed. I removed the brackets. Can anybody please confirm the operator that there will not be any impact? Also please provide if any documentation on operator precedence is available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know which database you are using such as mysql or posgres or MS SQL???

Comment: What database system? Also, any time you are hitting a limit like this, it's worth taking a step back and considering whether you're using the right tool, or using it in the right way.

Comment: it's oracle. the table is too big.

Comment: I wonder what these two similar conditions are supposed to do.

Comment: @ypercube it is a trigger's when clause

Comment: OK, but `NVL(N.col2,-1) <> NVL(O.col2,-1)` is the same as `N.col2 <> O.col2`. What is the point of using `NVL()`?

Comment: Hm, sorry. Actually they are not identical. Treat the previous comment as junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with or without the brackets, the result should be the same, in all SQL products that conform with the SQL standard.

The precedence of comparison operators, like `<>`, is higher than logical operators, like `AND`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can reference about operators.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx
2. http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95915_01/sqopr.htm
3. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE